Independence of maximums of independent random iid exponential variables.
Given Random Variables $X_1,...,X_n \sim Exp(\lambda)$, I want to show that for $m \neq n$ the sets $\{X_n = \max_{i=1,...,n} X_i \}$ and $\{X_m = \max_{i=1,...,m} X_i \}$ are independent.
My first idea was to show the independence of $ M_n := \max_{i=1,...,n} X_i$ and $ M_m := \max_{i=1,...,m} X_i$, however I get WLOG $m>n$:
$$ \mathbb{P}[M_n \leq t, M_m \leq t] = \mathbb{P}[X_1,...,X_m \leq t] = F_{X_1}(t)^m \neq F_{X_1}(t)^{n+m} = \mathbb{P}[M_n \leq t] \mathbb{P}[M_m \leq t]$$
I can prove it by considering tuples $(X_1,...,X_m)$ which indicate the order of the $X_i$ (i.e. $(X_1,X_2) \Rightarrow X_1 < X_2$) and using combinatorics.
How could I show that using probability theory instead of cominbatorics?

Assume $0<m<n$.
By symmetry, we have $\mathbb{P}(X_m>X_1,\dots,X_{m-1})=\frac1m$ and
$\mathbb{P}(X_n>X_1,\dots,X_{n-1})=\frac1n$ .
On the other hand, we have for $0<x<y$
$$(*){:={\mathbb{P}({X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{m-1}<x}\cap {X_m\in(x,x+\mathrm dx)} \cap {X_{m+1},X_{m+2},\ldots,X_{n-1}<y\cap {X_n\in(y,y+\mathrm dy)} })}\\[1ex]=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}(1-e^{-\lambda x})^{m-1}\,\mathrm dx\cdot \lambda e^{-\lambda y}(1-e^{-\lambda x})^{n-m-1}\,\mathrm dy
}$$
Integrating $(*)$ we get
$$
{\mathbb{P}(X_m>X_1,\dots,X_{m-1}\cap X_n>X_1,\dots,X_{n-1})\\=\iint_{0<x<y}(*)
\\=\int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty\lambda e^{-\lambda x} (1-e^{-\lambda x})^{m-1}\lambda e^{-\lambda y}\cdot (1-e^{-\lambda x})^{n-m-1}\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\=\frac1{nm}
\\=\frac1n \cdot \frac 1m
}$$
as required.


however I get WLOG $m>n$:
$$ \mathbb{P}[M_n \leq t, M_m \leq t] = \mathbb{P}[X_1,...,X_m \leq t] = F_{X_1}(t)^m \neq F_{X_1}(t)^{n+m} = \mathbb{P}[M_n \leq t] \mathbb{P}[M_m \leq t]$$

Yes, but that is not what you want to show.
Rather prove: $\Bbb P(M_n=X_n, M_m=X_m)=\Bbb P(M_n=X_n)\,\Bbb P(M_m=X_n)$

How could I show that using probability theory instead of cominbatorics?

Probability theory itself uses combinatorics.  Sometimes it is occluded, but it is often there.  Can you spot where?

The probability that the maximum is the last sample in a list of $n$ iid continuous samples, obviously equals $1/n$.
We may also obtain this by integration (letting the CDF and pdf be $F(x)$ and $f(x)$ respectively):
$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf P(M_n=X_n)&=\mathsf P(\{X_n=\max\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n\})\\[1ex] &=\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{\{{\max\{X_i\}}_{i=1}^{n-1}<X_n\}}) \\[1ex] &= \int_\Bbb R F(x)^{n-1} f(x)\,\mathrm d x \\[1ex] &= \int_0^1u^{n-1}\,\mathrm d u && u:=F(x) \\[1ex] &=\dfrac 1n\end{align}$
[Note: irrespective of which continuous distribution our samples follow, as long as the pdf exists.]

In the case of $n>m>0$ (and similarly $m>n>0$ by symmetry):
$\qquad\begin{align}
&\mathsf P(\{X_n={\max\{X_i\}}_{i=1}^n\}\cap\{X_m={\max\{X_i\}}_{i=1}^m\})\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(\{X_n={\max\{X_i\}}_{i=m}^n\}\cap\{X_m={\max\{X_i\}}_{i=1}^m\})\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{\{\max\{X_i\}_{i=1}^m<X_m\}}\mathbf 1_{\{X_m<X_n\}}\mathbf 1_{\{\max\{X_i\}_{i=m+1}^n<X_n\}})\\[1ex]&=\iint_{x<y} F(x)^{m-1}f(x) F(y)^{n-m-1}f(y)\,\mathrm d(x,y)\\[1ex]&=\int_0^1 u^{n-m-1}\int_0^u v^{m-1}\,\mathrm d v\,\mathrm d u \\[1ex]&=\dfrac 1m\int_0^1 u^{n-m-1}u^{m}\,\mathrm d u\\[1ex] &=\dfrac 1{mn} \end{align}$

Another, purely combinatorial approach: suppose $n>m$ and you order your variables in increasing order and mark them $1,2,\dots, n$. There are $n!$ ways to arrange them, but only $(n-1)!$ ways such that the $n$-th is the largest. For the $m$-th variable to be the largest amongst the first $m$, you must have $k$ (where $k\in\{m,m+1,\dots,n-1\}$) at the position $m$.
There are $\binom{k-1}{m-1}$ ways to select $m-1$ numbers which are all smaller than $k$, to be put BEFORE position $m$ (in order to that at the $m$-th position we have the largest of the first $m$ numbers). Once you selected them, there are $(m-1)!$ ways to arrange those before position $m$ and $(n-1-m)!$ to arrange the remaining numbers between positions $m+1$ and $n-1$ (inclusive).
Thus the total number of arrangments where at the $m$-th position we have the largest of the first $m$, and at the $n$-th position the largest of all is
$$
\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\binom{k-1}{m-1}\cdot(m-1)!\cdot(n-1-m)!
=(m-1)!\cdot(n-1-m)!\left(1+m+\frac{m(m+1)}{2!}+\frac{m(m+1)(m+2)}{3!}+\dots+\frac{m(m+1)\dots(n-2)}{(n-m-1)!}\right)
=(m-1)!\cdot(n-1-m)!\cdot\binom{n-1}{m}=\frac{(m-1)!(n-1-m)!(n-1)!}{m!(n-1-m)!}=\frac{(n-1)!}{m}
$$
and thus the required probability that both $m$ and $n$ are the largest values in their order is
$$
\frac{\frac{(n-1)!}{m}}{n!}=\frac1n\times \frac1{m}.
$$
